# Sort text numerically in powershell

Tags: powershell, sorting, text

I have some data in a text string that I need to sort. Here's a snippet:

```
0 X6300H_INJ.xtf CSFFILE0032
1 X6301H_INJ.xtf CSFFILE0033
10 X6309H_INJ.xtf CSFFILE0041
11 X6310H_INJ.xtf CSFFILE0042
2 X6311H_INJ.xtf CSFFILE0043
```

I need to sort this data numerically by the first column. How can I do this?

Comment: strip everything past the numbers, convert them to `[int]`, and sort on that. Something like `$RawText | sort {($_ -replace "(\d+)\D.+",'$1') -as [int]}`

Comment: Put it in a json file first with the first field as a number.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To build on [TheMadTechnician](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3245749/themadtechnician)'s helpful comment:

- Pass a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{... }`) to the [`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object) cmdlet's (positionally implied) 
  `-Property` parameter, which allows you to determine the sort criterion dynamically for each input line (object), accessible via the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_).
- Inside the script block you can split each line into fields by whitespace using the unary form of the [`-split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split), extract the first field, and cast it as an integer (`[int]`), which then serves as the sort value.

  - As an aside: If all input strings represented numbers as a whole, the solution would be as simple as:

    ```sh
    '1', '10', '9' | Sort-Object { [int] $_ } # -> '1', '9', '10'
    ```
  - Analogously, if the number (strings) to sort by were stored in a *property* of the input objects (note that just `Sort-Object Prop` would sort *lexically*):

    ```sh
    @{ Prop='1' }, @{ Prop='10' }, @{ Prop= '9' } |
      Sort-Object { [int] $_.Prop }
    ```

```sh
@'
0 X6300H_INJ.xtf CSFFILE0032
1 X6301H_INJ.xtf CSFFILE0033
10 X6309H_INJ.xtf CSFFILE0041
11 X6310H_INJ.xtf CSFFILE0042
2 X6311H_INJ.xtf CSFFILE0043
'@ -split '\r?\n' |
  Sort-Object { [int] (-split $_)[0] }
```

<sup>Note: `@'<newline>...<newline>'@` is a (verbatim) PowerShell [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings); `-split '\r?\n'` splits a multi-line string into an array of lines.</sup>

Output (correctly sorted by 1st column, numerically):

```
0 X6300H_INJ.xtf CSFFILE0032
1 X6301H_INJ.xtf CSFFILE0033
2 X6311H_INJ.xtf CSFFILE0043
10 X6309H_INJ.xtf CSFFILE0041
11 X6310H_INJ.xtf CSFFILE0042
```